# How to stop AppBarLayout minimizing on scroll up?

Tags: android, navigation

Im trying to stop the navbar which contains search and menu from minimizing when i scroll up. I have attached images of before and after user scrolls up.

I cannot find relevant element. Im not sure what its called.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: are you using a coordinator layout?

Comment: could you pleas provide your layout code

Comment: Im using coordinator layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the following code

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarEvents"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways" />


        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag="tab_indicator_accent_color,bg_primary_color" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: is it fixed or it just your xml ?